Alternatives to MOND not based on acceleration threshold
The mainstream MOND hypothesis purports different behaviour below some acceleration threshold. Is there some other theory in which gravity would behave differently based on some other condition? I wonder if outer regions of galaxies could rotate faster than expected due to some kind of galactic frame-dragging of the inner regions. Mach's principle has a related idea: "mass out there influences inertia here".

You can reformulate MOND's acceleration in terms of cosmological parameters as $a_0 = c^2 / R_u$ with $R_u$ the radius of the observable universe. For instance, quantized inertia theories rely on this relationship.
